# How to join and union multiple tables in SQL while keeping Non-Matching rows only once

Tags: sql

I have three tables:

1. Master Table A

| Key1 | Value1 |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| b | 2 |
| c | 3 |
| d | 4 |
| e | 5 |
| f | 6 |

2. Table B

| Key1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- |
| b | x |
| c | y |

3. Table C

| Key1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- |
| d | m |
| e | n |

Now I want to join A with B and C, in such a way that I get values from both B and C when the rows match but one row with Null if they do not match. Something like this:

| Key1 | Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | NULL |
| b | 2 | x |
| c | 3 | y |
| d | 4 | m |
| e | 5 | n |
| f | 6 | NULL |

---

Now, one way to go halfway is to Left Join A with B and C, and then union the results, and then drop duplicates. However, this might result in the dropping of unwanted rows in a few cases too and is not optimal. What is the optimal way to achieve this?

Comment: What if the same key1 value is in both TableB and tableC ?

Comment: Assuming this is not the case. Would be great to enforce this too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT A.KEY1,A.VALUE1,X.VALUE2
FROM TABLEA AS A
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT B.KEY1,B.VALUE2
     FROM TABLEB AS B
    UNION ALL
  SELECT C.KEY1,C.VALUE2
  FROM TABLEC AS C
)X ON A.KEY1=X.KEY1
```

If I understood your requirements correcly